# How to change the elasticsearch query to Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-java-api

I wanna code es aggregation in java. Can I change the query below to java?

```
... some query
"aggs": {
    "ip_address": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ip_address"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dup_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "updated_at": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
              ], 
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I think Using the AggregationBuilders provided by elasticsearch, it seems to be, but I'm not sure.Please help me.

Comment: please go through the link and provide your code, on top of which  can build the code if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use [AggregationBuilders provided in JHLRC](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-aggregation-builders.html) and build the queries, you need to use the [terms aggregation builder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.10.2/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/TermsAggregationBuilder.html) and [top tag hits aggregation builder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.10.2/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/TopHitsAggregationBuilder.html) for your aggregation.